# Ionic 2 Custom marker doesn't load from url in android device

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

Custom marker is not load showing in android device. In iOS is working.
When I get a marker from secure sites (https://) then is worked. But I want to show from without secure site.

**Add marker code for android**

**Custom marker is not shown below code.**

```
let icon: GoogleMapsMarkerIcon = {
    url: 'http://und.edu/_files/images/cta-homepage-visit.png',
    size: {
      width: 50,
      height: 50
    }
  };
  let markerOptions: GoogleMapsMarkerOptions = {
      position: location,
      draggable: false,
      icon: icon
    };

  this.map.addMarker(markerOptions)
      .then((marker: GoogleMapsMarker) => {
  }).catch(err => {})
```

**Custom marker is shown below code.**

```
let icon: GoogleMapsMarkerIcon = {
    url: 'https://lh4.ggpht.com/Tr5sntMif9qOPrKV_UVl7K8A_V3xQDgA7Sw_qweLUFlg76d_vGFA7q1xIKZ6IcmeGqg=w300',
    size: {
      width: 50,
      height: 50
    }
  };
let markerOptions: GoogleMapsMarkerOptions = {
      position: location,
      draggable: false,
      icon: icon
    };

    this.map.addMarker(markerOptions)
      .then((marker: GoogleMapsMarker) => {
    }).catch(err => {})
```

here only marker url is change. i want to display marker from non secure domain in ionic 2.
note: both demo is working in ios.
please help me
thanks

Comment: any errors in logs?

Comment: ok.. I suggest you add the solution here

Comment: It's taken much time to load.

Comment: Any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use tour icon-url in my code and it's working. I don't see too much difference between your code and mine, but you could try something like this.

```
let markerOptions: GoogleMapsMarkerOptions = {
    position: latLong,
    title: data.name,
    visible: true,
    icon:  {
        'url': "http://und.edu/_files/images/cta-homepage-visit.png",
        'anchor': [18, 36],
        'size': {
            width: 36,
            height: 36
         }
       }
    };
    this.map.addMarker(markerOptions)
        .then((marker: GoogleMapsMarker) => {
            marker.hideInfoWindow();
    });
```